# Rest Controller not returning correct reponse when using custom exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

Below is the service class and controller class for the spring boot application

```
@Autowired
private RecordRepository recordRepository;

public void insertRecord(String dest, Integer num) {
    try {
        List<Record> b = recordRepository.findByDest(dest);
        ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>();
        Record record = new Record();
        if (!b.isEmpty()) {
            for (Record r : b) {
                numList.add(r.num());
            }
            if (!numList.contains(num)) {
                List<Record> counts = recordRepository.findAll();
                ArrayList<Integer> countList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Record r1 : counts) {
                    countList.add(r1.getId());
                }
                Collections.sort(countList);
                int countInsert = countList.get(countList.size() - 1);
                record.setId(countInsert + 1);
                record.setDest(dest);
                record.setNum(num);
                recordRepository.save(record);
            } else {
                throw new DuplicateNumberException("Number already exists.");
            }
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundException("No records found for the given String.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("An unexpected error occurred while processing the request.", e);
    }

}
```

@Autowired
private RecordService service;

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<String> insertRecord(@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload) {
    try {
    String dest = payload.get("xyz");
    Integer num = Integer.parseInt(payload.get("num"));
    service.insertRecord(dest, num);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Record inserted successfully.");
    }catch (DuplicateNumberException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Duplicate number. Record not inserted.");
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("No records found for the given String.");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Invalid number format.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body("An unexpected error occurred while processing the request.");
    }
}
```

Whenever a call is made and the response should be either DuplicateNumberException or NotFoundException, I am getting reponse code 500 Internal server error.

I have tried including the if conditions in try block and catch the exceptions but it is breaking the flow of the app.

Comment: It will always throw a `RuntimeException`. You have one large `try/catch` around all your exceptions (the `catch (Exception e)`. Next to that this belongs in an exception handler so that it can be applied globally.

Comment: Could you please debug the code and check is your repository initialize  or not?

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please suggest the changes.

Comment: @AxelBlaze remove the outer try/catch, it's unneccessary

Comment: As mentioned here already but remove the outer `try/catch` in your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a close look at your code.  You have a nested `try/catch`.  In your outer `try/catch,` you're catching `Exception`, which is a superclass of every exception.  Therefore, any exception thrown by the inner catch will be caught by the outer, causing your method to throw a `RuntimeException`.

You need to remove the outer `try/catch`.

```
public void insertRecord(String dest, Integer num) {
    List<Record> b = recordRepository.findByDest(dest);
    ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<>();
    Record record = new Record();
    if (!b.isEmpty()) {
        for (Record r : b) {
            numList.add(r.num());
        }
        if (!numList.contains(num)) {
            List<Record> counts = recordRepository.findAll();
            ArrayList<Integer> countList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Record r1 : counts) {
                countList.add(r1.getId());
            }
            Collections.sort(countList);
            int countInsert = countList.get(countList.size() - 1);
            record.setId(countInsert + 1);
            record.setDest(dest);
            record.setNum(num);
            recordRepository.save(record);
        } else {
            throw new DuplicateNumberException("Number already exists.");
        }
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundException("No records found for the given String.");
    }
}
```